# How to use Chrome Webdriver cache for Whatsapp Web?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I created a script to send messages in an automated way through the WhatsApp Web.

However, I am not able to save the cache, containing the QR Code of Authentication, to the Chrome Web Driver through Selenium.

Each time the browser is opened to send a new message, reading the QR Code is requested again.

I'm using Ubuntu and Google Chrome on version 74.0.3729.157

What I've tried so far:

```
        options = Options()
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=./User_Data')
        options.add_argument("--test-type")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
        driver.get(url)
        time.sleep(10)
        python_button = driver.find_element_by_id("action-button")
        python_button.click()
        time.sleep(30)
        python_button2 =  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[data-icon='send']")
        python_button2.click()
```

Content of User_Data folder:

[image]

What's missing so I do not have to scan the QR code every time?